# Why does "and" work when specifying specific file extensions and not "or"

Tags: php

So I have this code:

```
$file= pathinfo($_FILES['screenshot']['name']);
$file_extension=$file['extension'];
if($file_extension !='jpg' or $file_extension !='jpeg'){
    $screenshot_error='Please upload an image in jpg format';
}
```

In my head I was stumped to why this code returned true in php, even when the file I uploaded was a jpg.
(sorry about that I wrote it returned false the first time)
However when I changed that 'or' to an 'and':

```
$file= pathinfo($_FILES['screenshot']['name']);
$file_extension=$file['extension'];
if($file_extension !='jpg' and $file_extension !='jpeg'){
    $screenshot_error='Please upload an image in jpg format';
}
```

It works just fine.
I wanted to know the reason behind this logic. Any insight would be helpful.

Comment: Where / What return value??

Comment: I think you have a wrong logic! In the first on it will give you every time a warning! In the second one if the file extension is equal to one of the file extensions it also gives you a warning!

Comment: when uploading file, you should check its mime_type, not extension!!

Comment: Actually http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php would be the best.

Comment: does your file have extention `JPG` or `jpg` ?? case sensitivity

Comment: @yiiframe Most likely my code is case sensitive. But the logic remains if I substitute the $file extension comparisons with mime_type comparisons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite logic statements with De Morgan's laws

```
not a or not b -> not (a and b)
not a and not b -> not (a or b)
```

What you want is not(a or b) which is equivalent to your Second example.

Comment: aka "De Morgan's Rule"

Comment: Thanks, I forgot the name and was to lazy to look it up :D

Answer (score 0):

Simple BOOLEAN logic

- File extension of `jpg`

`if($file_extension !='jpg' or $file_extension !='jpeg'){
               ^                            ^
             False                        True`

    False OR True = True

- File extension of `jpeg`

`if($file_extension !='jpg' or $file_extension !='jpeg'){
               ^                            ^
             True                         False`

    True OR False = True

Compared with

- File extension of `jpg`

`if($file_extension !='jpg' and $file_extension !='jpeg'){
               ^                            ^
             False                        True`

```
False AND True = False
```

- File extension of `jpeg`

`if($file_extension !='jpg' and $file_extension !='jpeg'){
               ^                            ^
             True                         False`

    True AND False = False

Comment: I didn't see the forest for the trees. I was so busy thinking of  examples that werent jpg's that I forgot about the cases that were.

Answer (score 0):

You put a wrong logic at first. When you using 'or' ,i.e., if the file extension was not a jpg file and not a jpeg file, the code would be executed. But you load a jpg file. According to your code it returns false. The right code is

```
if($file_extension =='jpg' or $file_extension =='jpeg'){
  $screenshot_error='Please upload an image in jpg format';
}
```

This code would be executed correctly when you chose a jpg or jpeg file.